# insert rows with sqlx, is it possible to avoid listing the fields explicitly?

Tags: go, sqlx

I'm using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) library like the following:

```
type MyData {
    Field1 string `json:"db:field1"`
    Field2 string `json:"db:field2"`
}

...

res, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO XXX (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?)", data.XX, data.XX)
```

Is it possible to avoid specifying "field1, field2" explicitly, and let sqlx create the query and binding automatically, e.g

```
db.Exec2("table_name", data)
```

I didn't find a relevant method to do that.

Comment: No. You probably want something like Gorm if that's the kind of functionality you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The package `sqlx` is just a wrapper around the DB driver. It is not an ORM. It expects user-supplied, valid SQL query strings. You may construct the query strings programmatically, and design some method that builds the column names from struct tags using `reflect` package, but why reinventing the wheel? The advantage of using a lower-level package as `sqlx` is exactly to maintain your own queries in exchange for not introducing an ORM framework in your codebase. With an ORM instead it is the other way around.

[Gorm](https://gorm.io) instead has a set of [conventions](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Conventions) that do what you want out of the box. You wouldn't even have to specify the db tags:

> GORM prefer convention over configuration, by default, GORM uses ID as primary key, pluralize struct name to snake_cases as table name, snake_case as column name, and uses CreatedAt, UpdatedAt to track creating/updating time

```
type MyData {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2"`
}

data := MyData {
    Field1: "foo", 
    Field2: "bar",
}

result := db.Create(&data) 
// results in something like this:
// INSERT INTO my_datas (field1, field2) VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
```